# Clang string as constexpr Apple vs Ubuntu. On Ubuntu not working. Fmt library

Tags: c++, string, clang, c++20, constexpr

This code happily compiles with:
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)

```
#include <string>
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include <fmt/core.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string abc = "{}\n"s;
    printf("%s", fmt::format(abc, 12).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

It fails with:
Ubuntu clang version 13.0.0-2

```
fmttest.cpp:10:18: error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal
type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>')
constexpr string abc = "{}\n"s;
```

Same -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++2b given as arguments.

Why two presumably identical versions of the compiler behave so differently?
What am I missing?

Comment: Your code lacks a `constexpr string abc` statement. Are you sure you're compiling the same code?

Comment: Adding constexpr doesn't change things much on Ubuntu.
constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>')